# iOS AR app shows black background rather than a camera overlay in production

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

Impossible to develop an augmented reality application on unreal engine. As soon as you develop it and try to distribute it on AppStore, the camera will appear black. This problem has been around for years and seems impossible to fix. Incredible!

In this link can you read official forum...
https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/ios-ar-app-shows-black-background-rather-than-a-camera-overlay-in-production/547275/38

You should see the camera shooting your surroundings, like all normal AR applications. But the screen is black :-(